# nodegit reset/revert single file

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodegit

I'm trying to reproduce the checkout file operation using nodegit for reverting current changes of a file.

```
git checkout -- filename.ext
```

My first attempt was to use checkoutRef function from Repository object, like this:

```
nodegit.Repository.open(gitRepo)
  .then(function (repo) {
    repo.checkoutRef('filename.ext',{
      checkoutStrategy: nodegit.Checkout.STRATEGY.FORCE
    }).then(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code: ;-)

```
try {
    const commit = await repository.getBranchCommit("origin/master");
    const tree = await commit.getTree();
    const resCheckout = await Checkout.tree(repository, tree, { checkoutStrategy: Checkout.STRATEGY.FORCE, paths: ["YOUR_FILE_PATH"] });
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `Reset.default` is what you want.